# Match camera to with photo with points

Tags: camera

I have a bird eye view of a site as well as accurately modelled topography and houses. I would like to get a perfect match of the bird eye photo and a blender camera. Fspy wont do the trick I don't have any clear axis and it isnt accurate enough. Ideally I would select a bunch of point on both the model and the image and a program would do the rest. Do you guys know of such a tool?

Ludvig

Comment: I think you would have to un-distort your source image before working with it in fspy. Scroll to the very end of this page to see an example https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-90/

Comment: Thank you, but by bird eye I dont mean fish eye. There is no distortion. Its simply too zoomed out and complex to have any dominant axis

Comment: Oh, okay my bad. Do you have any example of the type of image you are working with ?